# space piracy, has it ever happened?

Tags: history, law

Recently i was watching the movie "The martian" where

> Mark Watney has to take a rover on an unauthorized trip on what is considered international waters (because space can't be claimed by a country) and therefore is a space pirate

and that got me wondering, has something like that ever happened in real life, where someone (a person or organization) has became a space pirate, or a space thief?

Comment: Related, not duplicate: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2183/26446 and https://space.stackexchange.com/q/683/26446

Comment: Depends how much control one has to exercise to satisfy your definition of piracy, and whether the supposed pirate has to be in space: https://www.theregister.com/2011/10/28/us_government_satellites_hacked/

Comment: In the documentary "Battle for Salute", produced by Roscosmos, there is an episode which tells about a possible US attempt to kidnap a Soviet space station. https://youtu.be/Wxhv6GOLZqE?t=1200

Comment: @DrSheldon highest voted question of all time: [Can I borrow a lunar rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2095) (also slightly but not really related: [Hijacked space data, notable instances of recovering images or other goodies from someone else's space mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33359))

Comment: @A.Rumlin Wow, I wish I could understand the narration in this series. I wonder if google offers a translation from voice to text for videos.

Comment: Aw, man! Our evil plot to steal a space station with the shuttle leaked out. After all that misdirection about the spy satellites, too.  Hopefully our plan to launch hundreds of shuttles with orchid poison satellites in them is still secret...ooops

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is possible, but it did not happen.

Comment: @uhoh This episode tells about the shuttle's flight at the time when the station was out of order and about the peculiarities of its orbit relative to the orbit of the orbital station. And also about the design features of the shuttle, which could be used to transport the orbital station to Earth.

Comment: Does the plundering of german rocket scientist and launch vehicle equipment at the end of World War 2 qualify as “space piracy”?

Comment: @Paul not really, considering that wasn't in space

Comment: Does an Astronaut/ a Cosmonaut not giving back a pen to an other Astro-/Cosmonaut count as "space thief"?

Answer (score 4):

Not in a physical sense. Aside from the technical challenges (which are immense), a lack of interoperability and lack of in-space reprocessing and manufacturing facilities has so far made that sort of activity not worth the effort.

However, the United States and Russia (and probably China and some others) are working on defense programs that have some rendezvous and proximity ops (RPO) abilities. There is no open-source reporting that anyone has used these against unwilling targets yet, but if/when that does occur, I suppose you could think of it as a sort of piracy.

There have also been some efforts at civilian RPO activities such as the Mission Extension Vehicle: https://www.northropgrumman.com/space/space-logistics-services/.  Those capabilities could conceivably be used for "space piracy" though you likely wouldn't end up actually controlling the target other than in a physical sense, unless you also hack it.

Which brings me to hacking, or non-physical piracy. That absolutely has occurred, see e.g. https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/chinese-hack-us-weather-systems-satellite-network/2014/11/12/bef1206a-68e9-11e4-b053-65cea7903f2e_story.html.