# ISS nuts and bolts; Metric, SAE or both?

Tags: iss, unit-systems

The International Space Station (ISS) is a joint construction of many countries around the world.  Most of whom use the [metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system) for measuring including sizing of bolts, nuts and fasteners.

The US seems to be stuck on imperial units, while the rest of the world has moved to Metric and anyone who has worked on both an American automobile and one from just about any other place in the world, has found out the nuts and bolts are different.  In fact you need to have [two sets of tools,](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wrenches-inches-metric-us-conversion-comparison-d_1607.html) one SAE (American) tool set and one Metric tool set.

Are nuts and bolts on the ISS, metric, SAE, or both?

Comment: It's worth noting that NASA has stated they will only accept metric nuts and bolts on the Moon, although it seems the ISS still uses both.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto if that is the case, I am assuming that applies to new stuff as I suspect all the Apollo stuff is SAE, which means you might need to update [your answer here](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12359) if you don't have SAE tools, everything there now is just going to be scrap.

Comment: Yes, that only applies to future missions, I think the decision was made in 2004 or so. I'm sure they'd bring tools if they were going to work with Apollo hardware.

Comment: The US doesn't use the Imperial system of units and never has; it uses the *US* system. The Imperial system was created after American independence, and for understandable reasons wasn't adopted in the US. But both systems use the *international* foot and inch, so as far as nuts and bolts it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Erm...lack of SAE tools doesn't sound like an insurmountable problem: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/iss-nuts-and-bolts-metric-sae-or-both#comment31885_12394

Comment: @called2voyage I can't get a link to it but look at the follow-up comment by Organic Marble.

Comment: @JamesJenkins that's the current printer. You're talking about future missions, for which other printers would be available.

Comment: @called2voyage: I wonder how durable the 3D printed items are. Normally tools need to withstand quite a torque, especially if you tighten a bolt on an airtight, pressurized seal.

Comment: A great title for the question, BTW.

Comment: Ever-so-slightly related: [Are an aircraft's nuts and bolts generally either all Imperial or all Metric, or can they be mixed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32387/14213)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both, apparently, at least the ones the crew can access. Their toolbox features both [systems](http://toolguyd.com/iss-toolbox-tools/).

[image]

Comment: Is that a sonic screwdriver in the lower right of the tools? ;)

Comment: A closer look at the [image here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/timpeake/9131973816/in/album-72157634315750824/) makes it appear that darker blue is Metric and the Lighter Blue is SAE.  It is pretty easy to read some of the fractional socket sizes, the #mm are a bit harder to read in the photo

Comment: In most of the parts drawings I've worked with (granted they're for US-built components), all of the fasteners were NAS (National Aerospace Standard) parts, which generally follow SAE fastener sizes.

Comment: Is that the only toolkit they have?   I noticed a 3/8 to 1/2 inch drive adapter in the lower right; but the box appears to only have 1/4 and 3/8 sockets and ratchets.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Maybe some kind of [impact driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_driver)?

Comment: Note that they can also [3D print tools on the station](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/3Dratchet_wrench) now. So if you need some non-standard tool for the job, they'll just beam it up... :D

Comment: @Random832 almost positive it's a torque screwdriver.

Comment: That 3d printer only makes plastic tools.  OK for low-torque applications, I suppose.

Comment: Must be a `shopped image - I can see multiple 10mm sockets !