# Fate of human-made objects on Mars

Tags: mars, colonization, rovers, lander

Now that Opportunity is dead, and since there are ideas for future human missions to Mars, I wonder if there is a project to collect all our rovers and landers or at least label as historical sites the spots where they are resting.

In this [answer to an older question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20907/29357) about the lunar rovers, there is a link to a NASA's document with recommendations on what to do with the vehicles and sites. Are there any official documents with the same recommendations on Mars??

And what will happen to non-US landers?

Comment: A project to collect robots from Mars would really only be feasible once we have a permanent colony there, so I highly doubt anyone is even considering such a project.