# Moon Buggy Can Ride again?

Tags: rovers, lunar-rover

we all know on the moon there are 3 Moon Buggy's. If we go back to moon again some how find one of Luna rovers from 3 in moon will it be running condition if we give some Repairs?

Comment: The question on this site with the highest votes of all time is @JamesJemkins' [Can I borrow a lunar rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2095/12102)

Comment: After 50 years on the Moon all plastic parts and cable insulations need replacement. A lot more than some repairs.